# How to access js objects where keys aren't known

Tags: javascript, xml

How to access object elements in the example below where the keys are unknown

```
var person={{name:"john",username:"clap"},{name:"sandr",username:"poss"}}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Can you more clearly explain what the issue is? What are you trying to access?

Comment: Do you mean you would like to iterate over the keys? In order to ensure the best response, please take a moment to review how to ask a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This looks a bit odd. I assume you mean an array of objects?

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) might help you. You can use a for...in loop to loop over the keys or values of an object.

```
var obj = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};

for (const prop in obj) {
  console.log(`obj.${prop} = ${obj[prop]}`);
}

// Output:
// "obj.a = 1"
// "obj.b = 2"
// "obj.c = 3"
```